# HTML/CSS - How to make text-overflow in line with each other?

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical menu and some overflowing text and i'd like to make the text inline with each other. How would i do this?

For example:

http://i754.photobucket.com/albums/xx182/rache_R/text_zpsbd15aa0d.png

HTML:

```
    <div id="sideMenu">
    <ul class="top-level">
        <li><a href="#">Back</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Accessories & Merchandise</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Accident & Roadside Assistance</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Customer Relations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">E10 Petrol Compatibility</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Insurance</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Quality & Safety Actions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Servicing & Maintenance</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Servicing Offers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Warranty</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sideMenu {
font-size: 11px;
width: 185px;
padding-top: 35px;
padding-left: 15px;
}

#sideMenu ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#sideMenu li {
list-style: none;
padding: 9px;
padding-left: 25px;
}

ul.top-level {
background: #eceeef;
}

ul.top-level li {
border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
}

#sideMenu a {
color: #000;
curser: pointer;
display: block;
height: auto;
text-indent: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
width: 100%;
background-image: url(leftMenuArrowBlack.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left;
padding-left: 0px;
}

#sideMenu a:hover {

}

#sideMenu li:hover {
background: #fac026;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS code, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want..

Then make your width 200px for #slidemenu..

[image]

Comment: i would like the width to remain at 185px however, when the text overflows i basically want the text at the bottom to be indented the same as the text on top. For example in a paragraph, when you start a new sentence the text is always inline with each other

Comment: yes i would like the second  line to start at the same position as the first line

Comment: yes i would like the second  line to start at the same position as the first line

Comment: Just remove text indent property from "#sideMenu a"...then if your width is 150px it will remain same only..cool

Answer (score 0):

you can specify text-align:left/right/center in your css to align the text in the vertical menu

**Update**

you can remove the text-indent and padding-left on the li item and just add text-align:left

```
#sideMenu a {
color: #000;
curser: pointer;
display: block;
height: auto;
text-align: left;
text-decoration: none;
width: 100%;
background-image: url(leftMenuArrowBlack.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left;
padding-left: 0px;
}
```

checkout the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8U2H5/1/

Comment: unfortunately specifying text-align in the css had no effect on the alignment of the overflow